# interaction effects of marginal effects and its standard errors in glm with R

Tags: r, stata, glm, coefficients, marginal-effects

I viewed lots of relevant bloggers who explained how to generate marginal effects, but somehow most of them did not take interaction effects as sample.

When I use Stata to do it, the margin effects are quite easy to compute, but R seems in another way and show different results.

I want to know how to compute proper marginal effects with interaction properly,

1. why function `margins()` does not show the interaction factor?
2. if I compute this by hand `coef(glm)*mean(dlogis(predict(glm, type = "link")),na.rm=T)` ,it looks more close to the Stata result, not with the function `margins()`?
3. what's more, how can I compute the `standard error of marginal effects` handly, will it like this `sqrt(diag(vcov(glm1)))*mean(dlogis(predict(glm, type = "link")),na.rm=T)`  ?

```
trydata=read.csv("https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/palmerpenguins/penguins.csv")
trydata[c("species","sex")]=lapply(trydata[c("species","sex" )], as.factor)
contrasts(trydata$species)=contr.treatment(3) 
contrasts(trydata$sex)=contr.treatment(2)

try=glm(bill_length_mm ~sex+species+bill_depth_mm + sex*species, data=trydata)
summary(try)
summary(margins(try))
```

some links I saw before and thought useful:

[code: marginal effects with interaction](https://github.com/leeper/margins/blob/bd374239f5da0a92e8e27d093785850933fdfa9e/vignettes/Stata.Rmd)

[Marginal effects calculated by hand, but standard error doesn't show](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/245830_69d3604121ed437ba4b609347e7bdad3.html)

[Compare R vs STATA with various packages and functions: Interpreting Regression Results using Average
Marginal Effects with R’s margins](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/TechnicalDetails.pdf)

[Probit/Logit Marginal Effects in R](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2012/04/probitlogit-marginal-effects-in-r/)

[An Introduction to ‘margins’](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/Introduction.html#Using_the_at_Argument)

Answer (score 4):

I think `margins()` is  trying to prevent you from doing something that doesn't make sense.  There are a couple of reasons for the difference.

The most important is that when your x-variable (e.g., `sex`) is discrete (as it is in this case), the partial first derivative with respect to x is not meaningful because the idea of inducing an infinitesimal change to x doesn't make sense.  In your data, `sex` can be either male or female.  So, what `margins()` will do is calculate a first difference rather than a first derivative.

The other reason is that it is similarly not meaningful to think about the partial first derivative of the interaction term - the effect of changing the interaction term while holding the other terms constant.  You can't change the interaction term while holding the constitutive terms fixed.

So, I am not sure how you would want to interpret a marginal effect for just the interaction term itself.

As for the third question, you would have to use the delta method or a parametric bootstrap to calculate the standard error of the partial first derivative since the partial first derivative is a non-linear combination of the coefficients.

Comment: I upvoted this answer, but I wonder if it shouldn't be on https://stats.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Great thanks for you! but to be honest, I'm not good at math, too hard for me to understand the whole thing~

Comment: @IRTFM it could be there, but this is also about why R is doing something in particular. Perhaps it could go either way.

Comment: Sometimes the builders of R omit calculations they think are of questionable validity. Perhaps the real statisticians would have perspective.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [the `marginaleffects`
package](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/) to do
this (disclaimer: I am the author). For discrete regressors, the
function will report pairwise contrasts.

Load data and package, and estimate the model:

```r
library(marginaleffects)

trydata = read.csv("https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/palmerpenguins/penguins.csv")
trydata[c("species","sex")] = lapply(trydata[c("species","sex" )], as.factor)
contrasts(trydata$species) = contr.treatment(3)
contrasts(trydata$sex) = contr.treatment(2)

try <- glm(bill_length_mm ~ sex + species + bill_depth_mm + sex * species, data = trydata)
```

Average marginaleffects/contrasts:

```r
mfx <- marginaleffects(try)
summary(mfx)
```

```
## Average marginal effects 
##            Term           Contrast  Effect Std. Error z value   Pr(>|z|) 2.5 %
## 1 bill_depth_mm                     0.5189     0.1510   3.436 0.00058933 0.223
## 2           sex      male - female  2.9130     0.3376   8.628 < 2.22e-16 2.251
## 3       species Chinstrap - Adelie  9.9775     0.3347  29.812 < 2.22e-16 9.322
## 4       species    Gentoo - Adelie 10.4467     0.5814  17.968 < 2.22e-16 9.307
##    97.5 %
## 1  0.8149
## 2  3.5748
## 3 10.6335
## 4 11.5862
## 
## Model type:  glm 
## Prediction type:  response
```

Marginal Effects at Representative values, using the `newdata` argument
and the `datagrid` function:

```r
marginaleffects(try,
                variables = "species",
                newdata = datagrid(sex = c("male", "female"), species = trydata$species))
```

```
##    rowid     type    term           contrast      dydx std.error bill_depth_mm
## 1      1 response species Chinstrap - Adelie 10.610124 0.4738125      17.16486
## 2      2 response species Chinstrap - Adelie  9.333474 0.4730566      17.16486
## 3      3 response species Chinstrap - Adelie 10.610124 0.4738125      17.16486
## 4      4 response species Chinstrap - Adelie  9.333474 0.4730566      17.16486
## 5      5 response species Chinstrap - Adelie 10.610124 0.4738125      17.16486
## 6      6 response species Chinstrap - Adelie  9.333474 0.4730566      17.16486
## 7      1 response species    Gentoo - Adelie 10.824147 0.6424885      17.16486
## 8      2 response species    Gentoo - Adelie 10.062312 0.6493940      17.16486
## 9      3 response species    Gentoo - Adelie 10.824147 0.6424885      17.16486
## 10     4 response species    Gentoo - Adelie 10.062312 0.6493940      17.16486
## 11     5 response species    Gentoo - Adelie 10.824147 0.6424885      17.16486
## 12     6 response species    Gentoo - Adelie 10.062312 0.6493940      17.16486
```